# Issue with verifying an App Service certificate in Azure

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate

My ultimate goal is to automate this process in a Python script so I'm first familiarizing myself with the required workflow in the Azure portal.

Step 1 is to create an App Service certificate. In code, the call I make is:
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/aaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd/resourceGroups/my-rg/providers/Microsoft.CertificateRegistration/certificateOrders/my-cert-order?api-version=2015-08-01

with a payload of:

```
{
    "location": "global",
    "properties": {
        "productType": "StandardDomainValidatedSsl",
        "autoRenew": true,
        "distinguishedName":"CN=mydomain.com"
    }
}
```

Step 2 is to associate it with a specific keyvault. Again, in code the call is:
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/aaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd/resourceGroups/my-rg/providers/Microsoft.CertificateRegistration/certificateOrders/my-cert-order/certificates/my-cert?api-version=2015-08-01

with a payload of

```
{
  "location":"global",
  "properties": {
    "keyVaultId":"/subscriptions/aaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd/resourceGroups/my-rg/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/my-keyvault",
    "keyVaultSecretName":"my-secret-name"
  }
}
```

Step 3 is to verify the domain associated with the ceritificate that was just created. The instructions in the portal say to create a TXT entry at the root of my domain using the supplied domain verification token. I've done this but Azure doesn't like something as it never reports the certificate as being verified, even after several hours. I've tried doing a manual lookup of the TXT record I created and it is definitely available now, so I don't think that's what Azure is complaining about.

I know the REST call that the portal uses is verify-domain-ownership, as documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/appservicecertificateorders/verifydomainownership

I tried making this call explicitly in code and I can see that it is returning a 400 error, along with the following JSON blob:

```
{
  "Code": "CertificateResellerWebService_NOT_FOUND_TOKEN",
  "Message": "All remaining domain control tokens were not found",
  "Target": null,
  "Details": [
    {
      "Message": "All remaining domain control tokens were not found"
    },
    {
      "Code": "CertificateResellerWebService_NOT_FOUND_TOKEN"
    },
    {
      "ErrorEntity": null
    }
  ],
  "Innererror": null
}
```

Is the domain control token that it's complaining about here the same as a domain verification token? Whatever the case, the call is consistently failing with this same error. It's unclear to me what's causing this issue. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Update: This is the main algorithm I'm using for the process:

```
token = get_auth_token()
# First, put in a certificate request
cert_order = create_cert_order(token, CERT_NAME)
while cert_order.status_code == 201:
    cert_order = get_cert_order(token, CERT_NAME)
cert_order = cert_order.json()
# Then assign it to a specific key vault
cert = update_cert(token, CERT_NAME, KEY_VAULT_ID, KEY_VAULT_SECRET_NAME)
while cert.status_code == 201:
    cert = get_cert(token, CERT_NAME)
# Next, create a TXT entry in the root domain matching the
# domain verification token and wait for that record to be
# discoverable by nslookup.
domain_verification_token = cert_order["properties"]["domainVerificationToken"]
create_txt_record(domain_verification_token)
waitfor_txt_record(domain_verification_token)
# Finally, ask to have to domain ownersip verified.
response = verify_domain_ownership(token, CERT_NAME)
if response.status_code != 204:
    print("Domain ownership verification failed")
```

The functions create_cert_order, update_cert, and verify_domain_ownership referenced here represent the REST calls I've mentioned above. I'm pretty sure this workflow is correct, but I don't know why the final call is failing.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've posted the main workflow that I'm following for this process. If anyone is interested in the complete code, I can provide that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It should be the same. I can reproduce this code `CertificateResellerWebService_NOT_FOUND_TOKEN` on my side, which means Domain Verification is Pending, still not pass.

If you select manual verification. You could go to your DNS provider, then add a **TXT record** with name **@** and value **domain verification code** to your **root domain**. Note, if you add the domain verification for the subdomain, the same TXT record should add to that root domain instead of the subdomain. Please strictly follow these steps on the Azure portal.

[image]

Then wait for a few minutes for DNS propagation. If you still have any question, feel free to let me know.

Comment: This is exactly what I did, as I noted above, creating the TXT record as per the instructions. Then I waited and waited and waited but I always get the same error when I run a verify-domain-ownership. A manual lookup of the TXT record using https://mxtoolbox.com/TXTLookup.aspx verifies that the TXT record is discoverable but for some reason the verify-domain-ownership call fails.

Comment: Do you see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-domain-ssl-certificates#solution-4): `A certificate order has only 15 days to complete the domain verification operation. After 15 days, the certificate authority denies the certificate, and you are not charged for the certificate. In this situation, delete this certificate and try again.`

Comment: The only error I'm seeing is the message about the domain control tokens. I've also discovered that the process of requesting a certificate generates an email to webmaster@mydomain.com. There is a link in this message that takes you to a page where can click a button to approve the certificate. If I do that, then the certificate shows up in the portal as being approved, and in fact I don't even have to create the TXT record in this case. This is not a solution for me though since I want to automate the request/approval process.

Comment: I updated my original post to include the REST calls I make to perform steps 1 and 2. These work without issues.

Comment: From your original post, the step3, it sounds like you use the manual verification. Per my understanding, It will be ok if you select one of the three verification. Now you select the second methods: mail verification, this works. Actually, I answer you the error code is not passing the verification. Sometimes, you said you created a TXT, sometimes you did not. I feel It's confused. If you really do the manual verification correctly, I believe it will work.

Comment: Also, could you confirm how long do you order the certificate? it has more than 15 days?

Comment: The UI of course is just a wrapper over various REST calls that are made. In the calls that make up steps 1 through there is no explicit way to indicate that the certifcate is to be verified by mail, manual, or otherwise. The buttons in the UI don't actually do anything functional, they just tell you want to do. They are strictly informational. I don't actually want to use the UI in any event, I want to automate the certificate request and approval through code. So to keep things simple, lets forget about the UI and just consider what REST calls are needed to automate the certificate process,

Comment: Regarding how long it's been since I've ordered the certificate, it's been less that 15 days. I should be able to make a certificate request, create the require TXT entry, and then issue the validate request call, and in theory this process should only take 10 minutes or so, well under the 15 days. I've done the same thing for AWS and that's all that it takes.

Comment: In fact, the above step1 and step2 in your question are not related to automatically verify domain ownership. The real problem is that you could not do manual verification but select mail verification method to fix this issue.

Comment: When a certificate order is made, any of the available methods can be used to verify it. You do not specify which method is going to be used to verify it when the order is made. Rather, once it is made, you can use email, manual, or web to verify it. Once one of these methods has been completed, the call to validate-ownership is then made and this will complete the verification process. In my case, even though I'm creating the TXT record, the call fails. If I use the email method, the call succeeds. However, I cannot use email in my final solution since this cannot be automated.